# How hard should we enforce elisp coding conventions in posts on this site?

Tags: discussion

**Q:** How strenuously should we
enforce
[elisp coding conventions](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-lisp-style-guide) on this site?

Users (often new-ish to Emacs) sometimes post code snippets in
questions or answers that clash with pretty well-established
coding conventions for elisp.  The most common offenders are
trailing parentheses and using camelCaseNames in place of
hyphen-separated-lisp-names.

How proactive should we be in enforcing the conventions?

Answer (score 8):

I think a soft approach is warranted.

Be gentle to the newbies, point out the errors of their ways in comments, but don't come down on them like a ton of bricks. A light edit of their post is okay, I think, in order to enhance readability (especially if their indentation is off)! As they gain experience and reputation, be more strict with them. And be more lenient with questions than answers.

I find it hard to be more specific without some concrete examples.

Answer (score 4):

I would never edit those things in Question text unless it was so bad that the question was genuinely difficult to read.

I will always *re-indent* Question code which has been wrongly indented, as that absolutely makes it hard to read. This is the only aspect I feel should be *enforced*.

If posting a variant of such oddly-formatted code from the question in an Answer I will invariably reformat the code, which at least hints to the asker that their original formatting was non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

I feel a bit unqualified to comment given my lack of points.

But from a personal perspective someone editing my code to adhere to style guides is a very non-confrontational way to enforce these standards. Opinions may differ, but "oh you made that better: I'll do that myself text time" seems a lot less confrontational than "you have to format your code this way and follow these arbitrary rules".

This involves more work on the part of the editor / moderator, but perhaps this is precisely what makes it more acceptable to people: You care about this enough to do a little work for the answering and the community, so I respect your actions.

## Question as to how accepted these standards are

I have a little distrust of the legitimacy of coding standards. This standard is [mostly by one or two authors](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-lisp-style-guide/graphs/contributors) and [three years old](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-lisp-style-guide/commits/master?after=167a16e3e2a458613bdb04f68b2a1496d3eaa012+34) and moderately opinionated about some issues. My impression that lots of the accepted standards that people talk about in `elisp` comes from people experience in other lisps. I have been referred to [google's common lisp standards](https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml) before.

In addition, I would note that emacs is *very stateful* (marks, point, buffer, restrictions, windows) while lisp tends to be quite *functional*, which means this shipping of standards may not be legitimate.

**That said camel case versus hyphens seems a pretty straightforward question!**